# Form based visual studio project to single c# code and compile using codedom

Tags: c#, winforms

This code allows me to make a form based application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        string Output = "Out.exe";
        Button ButtonObject = (Button)sender;

        textBox2.Text = "";
        System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Linq.dll");
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
        CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, textBox1.Text);

        if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
            {
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text +
                            "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                            ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                            ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            textBox2.Text = "Success!";
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have to make the form and its controls programmatically. Can I convert the the program done in visual studio ( as a windows form application) to the input to this application thus avoiding whole coding?

Comment: I think you need to restate your question as I don't understand what you are asking, and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think that the idea is to put code into the text box and it compiles it into a standalone program. Theoretically, putting the contents of the .cs and .designer.cs files in there might do it, but it feels very prone to, well, not working.

Comment: I know making a form based application using visual studio (as Windows Form application). I want to create a customized form based exe application (child) using another exe that I made. I've to write whole code of child application as the input to the parent application. But it is easier for me to develop the child application using visual studio(by drag and dropping components). Is there any way to get whole code of the child application done in visual studio as a single c# program?

Comment: @ tjennings. You are correct. When I put code to the textfield and run it, I get a compiled application is output. This shows a cmd window along with the form I made programmatically in C#. This is totally annoying. I don't want this console window pop up and want to get an exe file same as we develop using visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to learn more about the way a Winforms project is built.  Do beware that the IDE provides lots of hard-to-see glue beyond changing the compile options from their default setting.  The code generators for resources, settings and the UI designer hide a lot of automagic.

Best way to go about it is studying the build commands that the IDE generates.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run.  Change the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" setting to Normal.  The Output window now shows you the command lines passed to the various build tools.

Good enough to show you what's missing from your snippet, you'll have to specify the compiler's [/target option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h25dztx.aspx).  Fix:

```
  parameters.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe";
```